# Issue getting a Date from a query stored to a Variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im having an issue with a date that im getting from a sql query and storing in variable.

```
<?php
$data=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT fe_ultima_act, DATE(fe_ultima_act) AS fecha FROM t012_caso WHERE estatus='cerrado' AND grupo_soporte='primer nivel' AND fuente='telefono' AND (SELECT MAX(fe_ultima_act) FROM t012_caso) GROUP BY WEEK(fe_ultima_act) DESC");
?>
var semanas1= [<?php 
while($info=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    echo ''.$info['fecha'].','; /* */
?>];
```

So if a run the query in the mysql console, i get a results like this "2015-04-20" and so on. But when it get stored in the var semanas1 is a value "1991"; Its actually making a subtraction of 2015 minus 04 minus 20.

How can i avoid that? i want to store the date like "2015-04-20".
Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Dont *store* the date like anything.  Make `fe_ultima_act` a datetime field put your dates in that way.  Then you can pull them out and *display* them however you want.

Comment: are you using it in jquery because i am seeing var there?

Comment: In addition this bit doesnt make any sense  `AND (SELECT MAX(fe_ultima_act) FROM t012_caso)`  There is no join there.  If it returns a value, it will return true, if not, false.  So you'll get all records or no records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're dumping PHP's output into another language.

e.g.

```
<?php
$foo = '1-2-3-4';
?>
var semanas1 = <?php echo $foo; ?>
```

when the above code is executed on the server and output to the client, the client only sees the **OUTPUT** of the code:

```
var semanas1 = 1-2-3-4;
```

That's just plain mathematical subtraction as far as Javascript is concerned. In other words, you have to generate output in PHP that's semantically correct for the environment PHP's output is going into. I'm guessing that's javascript, so you'd need something more like:

```
var semanas1 = ['<?php echo ... ?>'];
                ^-----------------^---note the quotes
```

or

```
var semanas1 = [<?php echo json_encode($date_string) ?>];
```

note the usage of json_encode, which guarantees that whatever comes out of php will be proper javascript.

Both of those would generate

```
var semanas1 = ['1-2-3-4'];
```